# sequential javascript pop ups - confirming a second time

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, page-object-gem

Does the page object gem support confirming two popups back to back? In other words, suppose you have a pop up that asks if you like cheese, yes or no. Given that the user chooses yes, another pop up would appear saying "you are about to answer yes," including an ok button.

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
@page.confirm(true) do
   @page.confirm(true) do
      button_causing_confirm_a
   end
end
```

Unfortunately, this did not work for me on my application. So instead, I tried handling the second pop-up with selenium-webdriver directly. Nevertheless, calling `@browser.switch_to.alert` throws a NoAlertPresentError saying that "No Javascript modal dialog is open". Anyone encounter anything like this?

Comment: Never encountered this...have you tried waiting in between the two switches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks MrTi, waiting between the switches actually worked! What a relief. The following would confirm two popups back to back:

```
@page.confirm(true) do
   @page.confirm(true) do
      button_causing_confirm_a
   end
   sleep 1
end
```